# Object not updating after localstorage get

Tags: javascript, angularjs, local-storage

In the following I try to test whether an object has been stored in localstorage, and if not to fill it with initial variables.

```
var TimerData = $localstorage.getObject("TimerData", "{}");

if(!TimerData.hasOwnProperty("timerState")) {
   TimerData["timerState"]             = "run";
   TimerData["timeOutMode"]            = false;
   TimerData["timeOutStartDate"]       = null;
   console.log("test line", TimerData)
};
```

However, running the console at line "test line" returns `{}` despite that I filled `TimerData` with variables lines before.

`$localstorage.getObject` looks as follows:

```
getObject: function(key, fallBack) {
      return JSON.parse($window.localStorage[key] || fallBack);
},
```

My guess is that the operation is dealing with async problems (taking data from localstorage takes longer).

How can this be overcome?

Comment: `$window`? `$localstorage`? What's with the `$` characters?

Comment: Probably nothing to do with async. And localstorage is supposed to be synchronous anyway. Have you tried adding more `console.log` lines? What did you get immediately after the `getObject` call?

Comment: If you're storing `localStorage` and `window` in jQuery variables, my question to you is "why"? If not, remove the `$`'s and make sure you have the appropriate camelcasing on `localStorage`.

Comment: I think the `$`-prefixed vars are probably local variables within an IIFE of some library. Many library writers like to use this type of prefixes to distinguish local vars. Sometimes, it gets to the ridiculous point of `$$$someVariable` if they have too many closures...

Comment: Could you post your complete code. 
I tried recreating the issue, and created this fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/drecodeam/cqsn8ujd/

Comment: I am writing my code in angular. For the questions on the $ see http://learn.ionicframework.com/formulas/localstorage/

Comment: After the getobject I receive {} when the app is loaded for the first time, which is expected. What I think is more weird is that I fill the object the limes before the console but thar it keeps showing it as empty...

Comment: Similar to Ankur, I also created a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/p5k4kc2k/ - Click "run" at the top to reload to the page after `localStorage` has been set. Seems to work for me?

Comment: Or, are you thinking `TimerData` is a reference to the localStorage item?? That is, `TimerData["timerState"] = "run"` would update the values in localStorage?? (reference vs value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jakee1 has the right idea but but you asked about angular...
Instead of

`var TimerData = $localstorage.getObject("TimerData", "{}");`

I would create local storage first, then assign a var to it.

```
$localStorage.$default({TimerData: {}});
var TimerData = $localStorage.TimerData;
```

This will only setup localStorage to {} if it doesn't exist ety

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are setting the value of "TimerData" to an empty object.

I think you can simplify this using standard js notation (you definitely dont need a special $localstorage adapter because you are using ionic). Ionic should respect standard js notation (although purely speculation on my part)

```
            var TimerData = localStorage.get("TimerData");

            if (!TimerData.timerState) {
                TimerData["timerState"] = "run";
                TimerData["timeOutMode"] = false;
                TimerData["timeOutStartDate"] = null;
                console.log("test line", TimerData)
            }
```